# How to select a specific value plus extra random values in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am pretty new to this but I am trying to make a quiz of 5 multiple choice questions. each question has 4 choices. 
I have the questions and their respective answer in a database. I am trying to randomize the questions and answers so each time a user takes the quiz it will show different questions.

Here is my code:

```
$qquery = "SELECT question from questions order by rand() limit 1"; 
$question = getvalue($qquery);  


$aquery = "SELECT (SELECT answer from questions where question = '$question') 
as right_ans, (select answer from questions where question != '$question') 
order by rand() limit 4";
```

The getvalue(query) function returns the question string. I am using that in order to find the right answer on the database. The function also runs the query and displays the results. My second query isn't working. I would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: Please show your table schema and sample data. It looks like normalization is in order.

Comment: You just want to randomize questions, then take them and search for the answer for that question in your second query right?

Comment: yeah that's what I'm doing, but I want the answer to be printed in a random position with 3 extra random answers from my table. Questions Table:
question_ID, question, answer, lesson_FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this new one, dont know, works with mysql or not.

```
$aquery = 
"SELECT TMP.ANSWER, TMP.RANDOM FROM (    
SELECT ANSWER AS 'ANSWER', RAND() AS 'RANDOM' FROM QUESTION WHERE QUESTION = '$question'
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT ANSWER AS 'ANSWER', RAND() AS 'RANDOM' FROM QUESTION WHERE QUESTION != 'question'
LIMIT 4
) AS TMP
ORDER BY TMP.RANDOM ";
```

Comment: wow thanks! that makes it much easier, however that query always displays the right answer first. When I add 'order by rand() limit 4' at the end it gives me all random results and not the right answer. It's strange. It looks like when I add 'order by rand()' it only takes the query after the union in consideration.

Comment: OMG! Thank you Aditya!! that works! I just have to modify my function so it doesn't display the random numbers as well :D

Answer (score 0):

With your current schema you can try it this way with one query

```sql
SELECT r.question, r.answer, q.answer wrong_answer 
  FROM
(
  SELECT question, answer 
   FROM questions 
  ORDER BY RAND() 
  LIMIT 1
) r JOIN questions q
    ON q.question <> r.question
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 4;
```

Sample output:

```
|  QUESTION |  ANSWER | WRONG_ANSWER |
|-----------|---------|--------------|
| question4 | answer4 |      answer9 |
| question4 | answer4 |     answer11 |
| question4 | answer4 |      answer7 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7219a/2)** demo

Obviously you read the question and the right answer once (e.g. from the the first) row and grab other 3 wrong answers from `wrong_answer` column while you iterate over the resultset in php.

---

or you can go further and pack wrong answers in a delimited list

```sql
SELECT question, answer, GROUP_CONCAT(wrong_answer) wrong_answer
  FROM
(
  SELECT r.question, r.answer, q.answer wrong_answer 
    FROM
  (
    SELECT question, answer 
     FROM questions 
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 1
  ) r JOIN questions q
      ON q.question <> r.question
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 3
) q
```

Sample output:

```
|  QUESTION |  ANSWER |            WRONG_ANSWER |
|-----------|---------|-------------------------|
| question9 | answer9 | answer6,answer1,answer7 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7219a/3)** demo

Then in php you always have a single row resultset. And you can easily `explode()` `wrong_answer` values.

Comment: Thanks Peter! but this query still sets the right answer always on the first spot. I appreciate the link to fiddle. I'm gonna keep messing around in there, see if i can figure it out.

Comment: No need to do this one in pure SQL. You can easily solve this one by using `$right_anwer_index = rand(1, 4);` in php and while rendering your page put the wright answer in this position.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I appreciate all the tips :) I am glad I found this site.